# how to extract single function from jquery library?

Tags: jquery, load, fadein, fadeout

I want to use only three methods from the jquery library without importing the whole library in my file, so is there any way to extract only fadeIn(), fadeOut(), load() from jquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could look at the source code and try to remove anything not required for the fadeIn and fadeOut methods, but you would likely end up with most of the library.

Overall jQuery is not designed to be taken ala cart, it is designed to be a single small footprint library. If it is not small enough for you needs, you might check out http://zeptojs.com.

Answer (score 0):

You'll find the source for the jQuery effects [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/effects.js), and you will notice that fadeIn/fadeOut are just shortcuts for animating opacity. So basicly what you need is the animate function, and that will need some of the other core functions etc.

The Ajax source is [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js), and it' basicly the same, load() is just a shortcut for jQuery.ajax, wich in turn uses other core jQuery functions.

You'd probably be better of just using the library as is, or searching the web and try to find similar plain JS functions for what you need.

Answer (score 0):

The `fade` methods are available a la cart, but they require "Effects Core".  See the "dependencies" section here http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/fade.  You can bundle individual libraries for download here:

http://jqueryui.com/download

`load` appears to be part of jQuery (not jQuery UI), so you can just load the jQuery library.  As @Karl Rosaen mentions, you can review the source and try to extract an individual function (find its dependencies too!).  Or you can go a little more native and start using XHR, or find a library that accomplishes the same functionality.